# ClickOnce app icon didn't update in some cases

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I help maintain a WPF application deployed via ClickOnce. When I first installed it, we were using Icon #1 as our app icon (specified by clicking Properties on the Project and setting the "Icon" field); this is the icon that shows up as the Desktop shortcut.

Recently our company's logo changed so I updated the icon to Icon #2 and deployed a new release to the ClickOnce server. On some of the computers running the software, upon receiving the updated release, the icon changed as expected. However, on a few, the old icon is still showing, even though I can see the program has updated to the latest version deployed in ClickOnce.

Why is this? Has anyone else encountered this? And what can I do to fix it? By the way, the program is self-signed; not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: was the update installed on all the machines ? coz it depends on user to update the software, they can chose not to update.

Comment: Yes it was installed. The app is set to auto-update, plus I confirmed manually anyway.

Comment: my users will click "Do not remind" and then cry out..... just wanted to make u aware about it... no more guesses from my side. just check if other changes were pushed ..

Comment: Yep, I appreciate wanting to cover all bases. But I've been on these machines and can see the new version number paired with the old icon.

Comment: do a file search for old file name on install location, may be that points out...